# Custom Eq Instance for Data Type

Tags: haskell

I'm having some issues getting to create my own Eq instance for my data type.

This is my code:

```
data Doc = Empty -- Adds ""
    | Text String
    | NewLine -- Adds "\n"
    | Concat Doc Doc -- Joins two Doc's

instance (Eq Doc) => Eq (Doc) where
    Concat a1 b1 == Concat a2 b2 = True
    _ == _ = False
```

My objective is that it only returns `True` when the final Doc is the same, for example:

```
*Main> Concat (Concat (Text "The ") (Text "birds"))(Concat Empty NewLine) == Concat Empty (Text "The birds\n")
```

This should be `True` and with the code I have it does return True, but it's returning True every single time, even if I have totally different sentences.

I've been battling around with this for a while and searched around but came up with nothing. Any of you guys have any idea or suggestion as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is actually very weird to define an `Eq` like this: it does not satisfy the *equality constraints*.

Comment: Whether this is a reasonable way to define `==` aside, what you've actually done is just state that any `Concat` is equal to another `Concat` regardless of what they contain.

Comment: This is a tricky data structure to write an `Eq` instance for, because simple recursion isn't enough. I assume you would want something like `Concat (Concat (Text "foo") (Text "bar")) (Test "baz")` and `Concat (Text "foo") (Concat (Text "bar") (Text "baz"))` to be considered equal.

Comment: That is, `Concat a b == Concat c d` can be true without `a == c` or `b == d` being true. Your data type doesn't provide a unique representation for a single document; it combines modeling a *document* with the concatenation operation on two documents. A simple type like `newtype Doc = Doc [Text]` seems more reasonable, with a separate `concatDoc` function to combine two documents into one.

Comment: Ah I see, I thought I was just checking that as well but didn't come up with anything else, I'll be giving it a try with all the suggestions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two questions here, so let's take them in turn.

**What's wrong with my definition?**

You define any two `Concat` documents as equal, regardless of what they contain. You also define any other values as inequal, regardless of what they contain. This means that, for instance,

```
Concat (Text "foo") Newline == Concat (Text "bar") Newline
```

gives `True`, while

```
Text "foo" == Text "foo"
```

gives `False`.

Let's write a definition for *structural equality* instead: two `Doc`s are equal if they have the same structure:

```
instance Eq Doc where
  -- Concats are equal if the things they are concat-ing are equal
  Concat a b == Concat a' b' = a == a' && b == b'
  -- Newlines are always equal
  NewLine = NewLine = True
   -- Two texts are equal if the text they contain is equal
  Text a = Text a' = a == a'
  -- Everything else is inequal
  _ = _ = False
```

**How can I write an Eq instance that doesn't care about structure, only whether the generated documents are the same?**

If we want to compare the generated documents, we can do just that:

```
instance Eq Doc where
  doc == doc' = generate doc == generate doc'
```

assuming that `generate :: Doc -> String` does what it says. We can also use `on` from `Data.Function` to write this as

```
(==) == (==) `on` generate
```

As William mentions in the comments, this "does not satisfy the equality constraints". However, there is precedent for this: the [diagrams](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams) package considers two diagrams to be equivalent if they generate the same instructions for drawing a diagram. The reasoning behind this is explored in [the paper introducing Diagrams](https://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1773&context=cis_papers):

> The particularly attentive reader may have noticed something
>   strange about this Semigroup instance: (<>) is not associative!
>   d1 <> (d2 <> d3) and (d1 <> d2) <> d3 are not equal, since they result
>   in trees of two different shapes. However, intuitively it seems that
>   d1 <> (d2 <> d3) and (d1 <> d2) <> d3 are still “morally” the same, that is,
>   they are two representations of “the same” diagram. We can formalize
>   this idea by considering Diagram as a quotient type, using some
>   equivalence relation other than structural equality. In particular, associativity
>   does hold if we consider two diagrams d1 and d2 equivalent
>   whenever unD d1 ≡ unD d2, where unD::Diagram → [Prim]
>   “compiles” a Diagram into a flat list of primitives.

Comment: Hey Rein, thank you so much, very very clear and deep but easy to understand explanation, have a good one mate :D

Comment: EDIT: I ran into some issues, my example should be returning `True` and it's giving me `False` instead

Comment: Which definition are you using? Your example is not structurally equal.

Comment: I'm using the first one since I was already trying to go down that way, reading your post again, I missed some information, I'll be trying with the generate, but just one thing, is there anyway to make the 1st example verify if the generated doc is equal instead of structure?

Comment: You could add a case for `Concat a (Concat b c) == Concat (Concat a' b') c'`, but that would only handle that one case. It wouldn't also handle `Concat (Text "foo") NewLine == Text "foo\n"`. There are too many special cases to handle elegantly. The easiest way to get non-structural equality is to do as diagrams does and consider `Doc` as a quotient type, using `(==) \`on\` generate` as an equivalence relation: "Two docs are equal if they generate equal things."

Comment: Ah ok, yea that would make it really limited, thanks for all your help and time, appreciate it, I've got it all figured out now thanks to you! Cya next time :D

Comment: You're welcome! Also FWIW: this idea of "transporting the question from a domain where the answer is hard to a domain where the answer is easy and then asking it there" is the motivation for Category Theory and, in some ways, most of programming.

Comment: What does "does not satisfy the equality constraints" mean, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, any `Concat` will be equal to another `Concat`. Let's try to check the equality by hand:

```
Concat NewLine (Text "Huh") == Concat (Text "Example") (Text "Concat")
= True -- inserted definition of `==`
```

We never look at the elements of your `Concat`. But at some point we have to check that `Newline == Text "Example"` and return `False`. An important hint is that you never inspect `a1`, `b1` and so on. As soon as we try to use them, the instance comes naturally:

```
instance Eq Doc where
  Concat a1 b1 == Concat a2 b2 = a1 == a2 && b1 == b2
  Text ...     == ...          = -- left as exercise
  Newline ...  == ...          = -- left as exercise
  _            == _            = False
```

Comment: Isn't this a complicated way to write `_ == _ = False`?

Comment: @ReinHenrichs because of the whitespace?

Comment: Because nodes are equal if leaves are equal, but leaves are never equal. The base case is always something that returns `False`.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs … time to log off for today. Sorry.

Comment: It happens to the best of us.

Comment: Thanks for your help Zeta, clear and straight to where my issue was :)